# Formatting a date retrieved from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am retrieving a date from my MySQL database in PHP using the current timestamp.

I get an output: `2015-09-29 17:51:35`

I expect this output: `29-september-2015`

Comment: Your title makes no sense. You also show no effort to accomplish this on your own.

Comment: Also you didn't explain why on earth you want to do this. *Note: you don't want to do this*

Comment: Show us your efforts done or read this out ->  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

With SQL use [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function for the disered output

```
select date_format(now(), '%d-%M-%Y')
```

Or with php, with [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
<?php

$str = '2015-09-29 17:51:35';
echo date('d-F-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
date('d-F-Y',$timestamp);
```

Read more on :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php